# Normalizr schema : nested entities does not become normalized

Tags: redux, normalizr

I have an Entity "term_attributes", whith two nested entities which don't become normalized. I use normalizr: "^3.2.2".

The original data is an array of products, here is the relevant bit:

```
[{
        "id": 9, 
        "price": "184.90",
        "term_attributes": [ 
        {
                "id": 98,
                "attribute": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Color",
                    "slug": "color"
                },
                "term": {
                    "id": 94,
                    "name": "Bags",
                    "slug": "bags"
                }
            },
```

The normalizing code:

```
export const termSchema = new schema.Entity('terms');
export const attributeSchema = new schema.Entity('attributes');

export const termAttributeSchema = new schema.Entity('term_attributes', { idAttribute: 'id'},{
    attribute: attributeSchema,
    term: termSchema
});

export const termAttributeListSchema = new schema.Array(termAttributeSchema);

export const productSchema = new schema.Entity('products', {
    term_attributes: termAttributeListSchema,
});
```

**edit**: forgot to add the productListSchema (not important though):

```
export const productListSchema = new schema.Array(productSchema);
```

Term_attributes are normalized, but not its nested entities (**attributes** and **terms**). Here is the result:

```
{
    "entities": {
"27": {
     "id": 27, 
     "price": "184.90",
     "term_attributes": [105, 545, 547, 2, 771]
},

"term_attributes": {

            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "attribute": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Color",
                    "slug": "color"
                },
                "term": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Fashion",
                    "slug": "fashion"
                }
            },
```

And if I remove the"idAttribute" from the termAttributeSchema, the normalize fails:

```
export const termAttributeSchema = new schema.Entity('term_attributes', {
    attribute: attributeSchema,
    term: termSchema
});
```

^^ What's wrong here?

**Update**:

Paul Armstrongs solution below works, and I just skip the `termAttributeListSchema`
and instead use the termAttributeSchema:  `term_attributes: termAttributeSchema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `productSchema` is incorrect. It should explicitly state that `term_attributes` is an array, which can be done in two ways:

Using `Array` shorthand:

```
export const productSchema = new schema.Entity('products', {
    term_attributes: [termAttributeListSchema]
});
```

Or using `schema.Array`:

```
export const productSchema = new schema.Entity('products', {
    term_attributes: new schema.Array(termAttributeListSchema)
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but it comes out wrong - so I skipped "termAttributeListSchema" and called termAttributeSchema directly: term_attributes:[termAttributeSchema] - but it fails for some reason(?)

Comment: Now it works suddenly!...must have been some temporary issue